# How to backup a NAS? Want to be able to recover files deleted by mistake

Tags: windows, backup, network-attached-storage, versioning

We have a NAS (HP Media Vault 2120) in a small office with 5 WinXP machines that save files onto one of the directories in the Media Vault. The vault is basically a centralized hard disk.

A couple of times people have deleted files in the Media Vault and we're looking for a way to be able to recover files, at least within a few hours or days of deleting them.

I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve too much time. I'm OK buying something.

Alternatively, if there's a way to set it up so that only some users can delete files but everyone can add/update them.

I'm spoiled. I used Dropbox on my personal machine and this would solve the problem. The issue is that we cannot save data outside the office.

Answer (score 1):

I'm kind of looking for the same thing. For onsite versioning I use Allway Sync, which is set up to sync every 3 hours, and move changed or deleted files into a special folder on the target. We use a time capsule (I'm an apple guy, and we needed something ASAP as our server died, so I drove to the nearest apple store and picked one up, as I knew it was good for the job) for the central HD, and then a windows box to do the backup to it's HD.

I'm looking for something to do reliable offsite backups using FTP- I've tried Allway Sync but after an hour or so it fails saying connection_is_dead.. Which might be (mt)'s fault, haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Media Vault software that came with your NAS to configure user folder rights. Google for the manual.

I usually buy at least 2 NAS's and use the second NAS to back up the first NAS. I set this up to happen at least once a night; more often if the data changes a lot during the day. This is a bit more expensive, but if you add up how much money all your data is worth I'm sure the cost of the second NAS will be more than worth the extra money spent.

Comment: How do you do the backup from one NAS to the other? rsync?

Comment: On our windows servers we've used both Delta Copy and regular batch files to run the backups. Delta Copy is an Rsync implementation for Windows. http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the MediaVault come with a copy of the NTI Shadow program for continuous backups?  You should be able to configure that for backups and then you can restore from that.